# Abbott's Exercise $6.2.14$ : Convergent subsequences for bounded sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I have been trying to solve the following exercise from Abbott's "Understanding Analysis".

[image]

I understand that $(a)$ comes from an application of the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem as we assume that $f_n (x)$ is bounded for all $n$ and $x$. But after that I do not understand how to proceed. Moreover the notation confuses me. If we have taken $f_{1,k}$ to be the convergent subsequence of functions evaluated at $x_1$ then what does $f_{1,k} (x_2) $ stand for?

Thank you.

Comment: It is too small for me to read.

Comment: @drhab That should do it.

Comment: Still too small for me. But if I guess correctly what it is about, you select a subsequence $f_{1,k}$ such that $f_{1,k}(x_1) \to y_1$. Then you consider the - bounded - sequence $ f_{1,k}(x_2)$. You extract a subsequence $f_{2,k}$ of $(f_{1,k})$ such that $f_{2,k}(x_2) \to y_2$. Then $(f_{2,k})$ converges on two points. Continue, extract a subsequence $(f_{m+1,k})$ of $(f_{m,k})$ such that $f_{m+1,k}(x_{m+1}) \to y_{m+1}$. Then take the diagonal sequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer It should be readable now. His subsequence notation seems to be the issue.

Comment: The "To indicate ..." sentence isn't so good, I think. Just note a) $(f_{1,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_{1,k}(x_1)$ converges, and b) for all $m$, $(f_{m+1,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $(f_{m,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $f_{m+1,k}(x_{m+1})$ also converges.

Comment: @DanielFischer So the sequence $f_{1,k} (x_2) $ consists of the same elements of $f_{1,k}$ evaluated at $x_2$ instead?

Comment: @DanielFischer I also do not understand why $(f_{2,k}) converges on two points. I understand one but the second one I do not see.

Comment: It is a subsequence of $(f_{1,k})$. Thus $f_{2,k}(x_1) \to y_1$, since $f_{1,k}(x_1) \to y_1$. And it is a subsequence especially selected so that also $f_{2,k}(x_2)$ converges to some limit $y_2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The lower double index confused me in a first read but then it becomes way clearer than the "natural" alternative )index of index of index...): the book begins with $\;f_{n_1}\;$, i.e. one single index with one subindex, so I think the intention is:

Prove there exists a subsequence of $\;\{n_k\}\subset\{n\}\;$ s.t. that $\;\{f_{n_k}(x_1)\}:=\left\{f_{1,k}(x_1)\right\}\;$ converges. This is straighforward B-W and we get a converging subsequence  as defined by Abbot just above (b) in his book.

Since the sequence $\;\left\{f_{1,k}(x_2)\right\}\;$ is bounded, there exists a subsequence $\;\left\{{2,k}\right\}\subset\left\{{1,k}\right\}\;$ s.t. $\;\left\{f_{2,k}(x_2)\right\}\;$ that converges.

Continues as above: there exists a subsequence $\;\left\{f_{3,k}(x_3)\right\}\;$ that converges and etc.

Comment: In your last line, there might be not elements in common as the functions are evaluated at different values. I do not understand why one is a subset of the other.

Comment: You're right, that's a copy&paste typo when I was trying to write that the sequences of subindexes are subsequences of the preceeding one. Thanks

Comment: Okay thank you. Then what about part c? Where does Cantor's diagonalisation method enter?

Comment: I think the intention here is for you to form "a grid"$$\begin{cases}f_{1,1}(x_1)&f_{1,2}(x_1)&\ldots\\
f_{2,1}(x_2)&f_{2,2}(x_2)&\ldots\\\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\end{cases}$$

and now choose the "main diagonal"  $$ \left\{f_{1,1}(x_1),\,\,f_{2,2}(x_2),\,\,\ldots,\,f_{m,m}(x_m)\,,\ldots \right\} $$

Comment: According to one solution manual I have come across, this is important because the main diagonal is a subsequence of $f_{1,k}$ and therefore $f_{k,k} (x_1)$ converges but of course I still have to understand what these phrases mean.

Comment: Yes, you still have...Read carefully Cantor's wonderful diagonal trick in that proof in the zone of 1.5.1 in the book.

Comment: My problem again is that it is not the same value of $x$. It cannot be a subset therefore.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean @JohnK ...I shall give it a little thought later.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for all your effort. I think this is a very badly phrased part of the book.