# Abbott's Understanding Analysis question 6.2.14

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

There is already a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724556/abbotts-exercise-6-2-14-convergent-subsequences-for-bounded-sequences-of-fu) regarding exercise 6.2.14 from Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis in this site.  But it does not answer my question.  The Question is posed below, and my question below it.

[image: Abbott 6.2.14]

My question is what exactly the notation $f_{1,k}$ means ?. From what I understand from the question, $f_{1,k}$ means a subsequence of $f_n$ evaluated at the point $x_1$ i.e. the first index indicated the data point at which the functions are evaluated and second index $k$ simply means that it is a subsequence  i.e. $k \subseteq [n]$. So in effect, $f_{1,k}$ is always evaluated at $x_1$. Then what exactly $f_{1,k}(x_2)$ means ?.

Answer (score 1):

$(f_{n}(x_{1}))_{n}$ is a sequence of numbers. The author claims
that we can find a sequence $(n_{k})_{k}$ with $n_{1}\leq n_{2}\leq\cdots$ such that $(f_{n_{k}}(x_{1}))_{k}$ converges.

Next, note that $(f_{n_{k}})_{k}$ is a sequence of functions. To simplify notation, the author defines $f_{1,k}=f_{n_{k}}$ (the $1$ is to stress that the sequence $(n_{k})_{k}$ was picked with respect to $x_{1}$). Therefore, the sequence of functions $(f_{n_{k}})_{k}$ can now be written $(f_{1,k})_{k}$.

Next, note that $(f_{1,k}(x_{2}))_{k}$ is a sequence of numbers corresponding to evaluating the functions $f_{1,k}$ at the point $x_{2}$.

Comment: So $(f_{n_k})_k$ is a sequence of functions like, for example, $f_1,f_2,f_3\cdots f_k$ and $f_{i,k}$ simply means that evaluating those sequences at $x_i$ ?

Comment: No. In the author's construction, $f_{n_1}, f_{n_2}, \ldots$ is the same sequence as $f_{1,1}, f_{1,2}, \ldots$. These are not being evaluated. When the author writes $f_{1,1}(x_2), f_{1,2}(x_2), \ldots$, the sequence is being evaluated at $x_2$.

Comment: sorry did not understand it completely.  In your comment what is $f_{1,1}$ ?. What is that function corresponds to ?.

Comment: $f_{1,k}$ is the same function as $f_{n_k}$. The author just relabels it to stress the fact the **numerical** sequence $(f_{1,k}(x_1))_k$ converges.

Comment: I think your confusion stems from the fact that the author goes back and forth between **sequences of numbers** and **sequences of functions**. These two things are not the same. Make sure you understand this distinction.

Answer (score 1):

By Bolzano-Weierstrass, every bounded sequence of real numbers contains a convergent subsequence.   Define $f_{m,k}$ to be that subsequence of $f_{m-1,k}(x_m)$ for each $m$, starting with $f_{2,m}:=$ a convergent subsequence of $f_{1,k}(x_2)$.

So,  the point is that $f_{1,k}$, though it is a convergent subsequence when evaluated at $x_1$, can also be evaluated at $x_2$ (or any $x$, for that matter).

I suggest reading (a) again carefully...  Abbott explains that the $(f_{n_k})$ are *generated* by the subsequence of real numbers gotten by evaluating the $(f_n)$ at $x_1$...  this is done by taking the index ($n_k$) of the function corresponding to the $n_k$th number in the subsequence...

Comment: In your last sentence, you said 'can also be evaluated at $x_2$'. That is the part troubling me. $f_{1,k}$ is the sub-sequence of numbers where the function is evaluated at $x_1$. Then how it can be evaluated again at $x_2$ ? Or is it like, $f_{1,k}(x_2)$ is the sub-sequence corresponding to $f_{1,k} \cap f_{2,k}$ ?

Comment: There's a sequence of _functions_, $f_{1,k}$, as distinct from the numbers $x_i$.

Comment: It's confusing because he goes back and forth between (sub)sequences of real numbers and the corresponding sequences of functions...

Comment: Ok. Can you explain $f_{1,k}$ in terms of $f, x_i$ and $n$ ?.

Comment: $f_{1,k}=f_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $f_n$ such that $f_{1,k}(x_1)$ is a convergent subsequence of the bounded sequence of real numbers $f_n(x_1)$ (which is guaranteed by Bolzano-Weierstrass).